Feijóo dice que el problema es de Sánchez, no de España: "Estamos ante un tic autoritario no visto desde Franco"
Feijóo dice que el problema es de Sánchez, no de España: "Estamos ante un tic autoritario no visto desde Franco"
"un tic autoritario"
¿Qué es esto por favor?
https://www.rtve.es/noticias/20240427/feijoo-pp-sanchez-engano/16079590.shtml


tic De la onomat. tic.1. m. Movimiento convulsivo, que se repite con frecuencia, producido por la contracción involuntaria de uno o varios músculos.

RAE
Es una forma peyorativa de decir que Sánchez, candidato del partido progresista de España, posee y manifiesta fórmulas con actitudes correspondientes a autoritarismos de otra épocas en repetidas ocasiones.
